# How do multiple recursive calls execute in merge sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

After understanding how merge sort works I am having trouble with the implementation :

I have this method called from main:

```
void sort(int arr[], int beg, int end)  
{  
    if (beg<end)  
    {  
        int mid = (beg+end)/2;  
        sort(arr, beg, mid);   //call a 
        sort(arr , mid+1, end);  //call b
        merge(arr, beg, mid, end);  
    }  
}
```

How do the 2 recursive calls execute?

The first one is changing beginning and end values every time, when the first recursive call stops executing (end>beg) does the second one start with the last values modified or the initial ones?

I can't see how it would start with the initial ones and starting with the last ones doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, didn't really understand what's going on which is why I am here, sorry.

Comment: If the issue is generally with recursion perhaps you should start with a minimal example like a recursive sum or factorial to see the mechanics of recursive calls. And if the issue is with interpreting the debugger info, writing down each individual recursive call on paper, what goes in, what goes out, may help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `array` of length of 5, like `arr[] = {3,5,4,1,2}`
So the subsequent recursive callings after first `sort(arr,0,5)` would be

`CALL#1: sort(a,0,2)
 CALL#2:     sort(a,0,1)
 CALL#3:         sort(a,0,0)
 CALL#3:         sort(a,1,1)
 CALL#2:     sort(a,2,2)
 CALL#1: sort(a,3,5)
 CALL#4:     sort(a,3,4)
 CALL#5:         sort(a,3,3)
 CALL#5:         sort(a,4,4)
 CALL#4:     sort(a,5,5)`

When a new recursive call is initiated, current variable values are stored in stack and method is called with new values. It then executes this new call with these new values. Once this call is returned, it picks the values from stack and continues with the old values.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, when function is called all it's local variables are created on `stack`(i.e stack pointer incremented by amount of local variables used). Upon function exit stack pointer is decremented by same amount.

Consider below example, function `foo()` with some bytes of local variables calling a `bar()` with some other bytes of local variable. (For simplistic purpose I have excluded the function return  address from stack and function doesn't have arguments)

```
 /*stack growth in this direction ---->*/


 foo()-------+
             |
    /*foo code execution */
             | 
           bar()----------+
                          |
                  /* bar() Code execution */
                          | 
             +------------+
             |
|------------+
```

As functions is called stack is expanded and it shrinks upon function exit.

In case of recursive function `bar()` happens to be `foo()` again and again. But on new stack location for every function call.

> How do the 2 recursive calls execute?

In your case recursive call of function `sort` will create `beg` and `end` at different stack location and will not conflict or alter local variable of previous function call.

> when the first recursive call stops executing (end>beg) does the second one start with the last values modified or the initial ones?

First recursive call exits on condition `(end>=beg)`

Consider below example to understand when first recursive call will exit,

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

sort(a,0,4)------>+
                  |
              sort(a,0,2)------>+
                                |
                           sort(a,0,1)----->+
                                            |
                                       sort(a,0,0)----->+
                                                        |
                                                    //0< 0
                                                        |
                                            |<----------+
                                            |
                                        sort(a,1,1)---->+
                                                        |
                                                    //1< 1
                                                        |
                                            |<----------+
                                            |
                                         merge(a, 0, 0, 1)
                                            |
                                |<----------+
                                |
                           sort(a,2,2)----->+
                                            |
                                         //2 < 2
                                            |
                                |<----------+
                                |
                        merge(a, 0, 1, 2)   
                                |
                    |<----------+
                    |           
              sort(a,3,4)------>+
                                |
                           sort(a,3,3)----->+
                                            |
                                       //3 < 3
                                            |
                                |<----------+
                                |
                           sort(a,4,4)----->+
                                            |
                                         //4 < 4
                                            |
                                |<----------+
                                |
                             merge(a, 3, 3, 4)
                                |
                    |<----------+           
                    |
                merge(a, 0, 2, 4)
                    |
|<------------------+
```